# Problem in VariationsRootLanding.ascx and a Domain entry

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, domain

I have a problem with my client's live environment and a concept known as Variations in SP2007.

They're domain, http://www.clientweb.co.za forcefully redirects the user to http://www.clientweb.co.za/en/pages/home.aspx but causes an error within the VariationsRootLanding.ascx with a FileNotFound exception. I tried to search the webs for similar issues but not a lot of help has been given around why this error occurs.

I found a blog post where the guy explains that AAM entries for the domain name might not exist. I have verified the entries in AAM and they all appear (at least for me) fine. The error occurred after we extended http://www.clientweb.co.za to a new port so we can enable Forms Authentication on the site (live deployment) and now we cannot get around this error.

**Update**

-- Hi guys, just an update to this one. The problem occured in the load-balanced environment where the user as redirected from front-end-x to front-end-y and could not deduce the culture info from front-end-x. This was an oversight on our part as part of the deployment.

Thanks,

Eric